# Prove equivalence of two regex using basic identities.

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm trying to prove the following identity

$$
(x+y)^* = (x^*y)^*x^* = x^*(yx^*)^*
$$

Using the following 12 identities

1. $L + M = M + L$
2. $(L + M) + N = L + (M + N)$
3. $(LM)N = L(MN)$
4. $\emptyset + L = L + \emptyset = L$
5. $\epsilon L = L \epsilon = L$
6. $\emptyset L = L \emptyset = \emptyset$
7. $L(M + N) = LM + LN$
8. $(M+N)L = ML + NL$
9. $L + L = L$
10. $(L^*)^* = L^*$
11. $\emptyset^* = \epsilon$
12. $\epsilon^* = \epsilon$

My problem is that I cannot seem to get rid of the $*$ on the right side, no matter what I do. Any hint would really be appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully you're not using "identity" 10

Comment: Sorry. I forgot the *. They should be correct now.

Comment: are these the only identities you are allowed to use? laws such as $(b + ay) \leq y => a^*b \leq y$ would be very useful here

Comment: Yes. These are the only ones I'm supposed to use.

Comment: Im unsure if its possible to do so without a rule like the one above, since every complete "axiomatization" Ive seen includes an order rule. But maybe someone will show otherwise!

Comment: It is clear that $x^*(yx^*)^* \leq (x+y)^*$. So it suffices to show that $(x+y)^* \leq x^*(yx^*)^*$. Using the axiom I have given in comments above, it suffices to show that $e + (x+y)(x^*)(yx^*)^* \leq (x^*)(yx^*)^*$. But then we only need to show that  $x(x^*)(yx^*)^* \leq (x^*)(yx^*)^*$ and $y(x^*)(yx^*)^* \leq (x^*)(yx^*)^*$ and this is clear

Comment: ^heres a proof with axiom above, for reference

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot obtain your identity this way. Indeed, suppose you define $L^*$ by $L^* = \varepsilon + L$. Then the 12 identities are satisfied, but the new wanted one fails to be true.